# Proof of the Pohozaev Identity

Tags: analysis, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-analysis, variational-analysis

I would like to prove the following result:
Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function and $F(u)=\int_{0}^uf(s)ds$. Let $u\in C^2(\Omega)\cap C^1(\overline{\Omega})$ be such that $-\Delta(u)=f(u)$ in $\Omega$ and $u=0$ on $\partial \Omega$, where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a domain.
Then, the following equality holds:

$$\frac{n-2}{2}\int_{\Omega}|\nabla u|^2 \, dx-n\int_{\Omega}F(u)\, dx+\frac{1}{2}\int _{\partial \Omega}\left|\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}\right| ^2 x\cdot\nu \, d\sigma=0,$$

where $\nu$ is the normal pointing outwards $\partial\Omega$.

The proof I'm trying to understand on Struwe, "Variational Methods"
states the following result:

$0=(\Delta u+f(u))(x\cdot \nabla u)=\operatorname{div} (\nabla u(x\cdot\nabla u))-|\nabla u|^2-x\cdot\nabla(\left|\frac{\nabla u}{2}\right|^2)+x\cdot\nabla F(u)$.

My question is: how can I use the Divergence in this way, in particular how can I pass from $f$ to $F$ in this result?

Moreover, how can I deduce the equality I want to show from this result? (I know that Divergence Theorem must be involved).

Comment: Calculate $\nabla F$.

Comment: I think $\left|\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}\right|$ (in the last term of LHS) should be $\left|\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}\right|^2$?
I found the original paper of Pohozaev here: [Pohozaev's article](http://www.mathnet.ru/links/3d012ceac71b7565323f06a5c08c5e68/dan31757.pdf)